# How do I generate a Pdf from a Base64 string and return it to the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I have tried following the previous questions, and nothing seems to work. The ActionController Method block which I am using to generate the Pdf is as follows:

```
string attachment = "JVBERi0xLjcKJcKzx9gNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwvTmFtZXMgPDwvRGVzdHMgNCAwIFI+PiAvT3V0bGluZXM...dFgMXKmE4dxUhIRnQJ5EHlF2A52ZuSnWJI7HBR/w7P0UGdopUkbO8wqocFUT0J64sTKnSWqThIS88yys==";
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment);
System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\"+randomGenerator()+".pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
writer.Close();
```

I was also getting an error earlier about the Base64String length being invalid. I solved that by adding an '==' to the end of the string, but it still won't generate the Pdf. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where is the base64 string from? How is it generated? I am afraid it is invalid, either with or w/o the ending ==s

Comment: I am generating them like this:

                        string filetype = http.ContentType;
                        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(http.InputStream))
                        {
                            bytes = br.ReadBytes(http.ContentLength);
                        }
                        string a = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Comment: And, the Base64string is valid. I checked it here https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: Well this code works fine on my machine. So I assume maybe the data you recieve is is incorrect format (probably not binary). Try my example (just add path to the pdf) it works fine:
 `var pathToFile ="";
    var pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile);
 string attachment = Convert.ToBase64String(pdf);;
 byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment);
 var newName ="test.pdf";
 System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(newName, FileMode.CreateNew);
 System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
 writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
 writer.Close();`

Comment: I used another base64 string and it still gives me an error. It shows me a blank PDF Page with the error "Failed to load PDF". Am I missing a step somewhere because everything else is exactly the same as @lucky125111 has mentioned

Comment: @lucky125111 did you make any changes to your .config file to change the encodings? The sample pdf file which I am uploading occupies 97kB whereas the one which I am downloading occupies 137kB.

Comment: @reddevil_j try this base64, it's some documentation from graphwiz (5kb file) https://pastebin.com/UmrswrN3. I didn't changed any encoding and run my query in linqpad

Comment: @lucky125111 it works for me now. The SQL query which I was using was not retrieving the entire Base64String for me. It does now and it works. The issue was with the input string. Thanks for helping me!